# Spotipy + Telegram bot is not sending messages to channel

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, spotipy

I'm currently developing a Telegram Bot that should send a message every time a new song is added to my playlist.

The code is giving me no errors and I'm currently testing it in Visual Studio Code. Where am I wrong?

```
import os
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from telegram import Bot, Update, Message
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters
import asyncio

# Set credentials for Spotify
os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID"] = "---"
os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET"] = "---"
os.environ["SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI"] = "http://localhost/"

# Set Telegram's bot credentials
telegram_token = "---"

# Create an instance for Telegram's bot
bot = Bot(token=telegram_token)
updater = Updater(bot=bot, use_context=True)

# Spotify Playlist ID
playlist_id = "---"

# Function to send messages in Telegram
async def send_message_to_channel(bot: Bot, chat_id: str, message: str):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

# Function to check new songs in the playlist
async def check_new_songs(bot: Bot, chat_id: str):
    spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope="playlist-read-private", open_browser=False))
    results = spotify.playlist_tracks(playlist_id)
    tracks = results["items"]

    for track in tracks:
        song_name = track["track"]["name"]
        artist_name = track["track"]["artists"][0]["name"]
        message = f"We added a new song: {song_name} - {artist_name}"
        await send_message_to_channel(bot, chat_id, message)


# Create an async task to check new songs
async def check_songs_periodically():
    while True:
        check_new_songs(bot, "@telegramgroup")
        await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Every 60 seconds

# Start async loop
asyncio.ensure_future(check_songs_periodically())

# Start bot
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Obviously all the credentials have been filled in my original code.
EG: I've forced the version of the telegram library because I was getting errors on the "Filters" variable. I've already tried to revoke the bot's token and to change the group the bot were supposed to post. The Spotify's app is set and the bot has all the permissions he needs.